# Stop the execution of foreach loop which extract data from array?

Tags: email, php, membership

In detail the condition is
There are multiple new users to whom admin want to send welcome message but only once for each member. I have done sending message but if the member refresh his email page than the code execute again and new message is send to him by admin and i want to stop sending multiple mail even after he reload his mail page.

> $rcvr_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_users ORDER BY ID ");
>     foreach($rcvr_id as $rv_id)
>     {
>       $rcvr_id = $rv_id->ID;

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mail_messages";
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$rows = array(
    array(
        'sender_id' => 4, // who send mail to new members
        'receiver_id' => $rcvr_id, // new members who recieve mail just once from sender above
        'sent_date' => $date,
        'thread_id' => 1,
        'subject' => 'Welcome',
        'text_message' => 'You are welcome to our world.',
        'send_del_message' => 0
        )
    );

foreach( $rows as $row )
{

    $sndr_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT sender_id FROM wp_mail_messages ");
//echo $sndr_id;

    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $row);

} 
if($sndr_id != 4){
    break;

}
```

}

This is code which send mail to all members but continue sending on each refresh of page by receiver.

Answer (score 0):

It has probably more systematical solution, but one option is to save the highest recipient ID, and then load only higher IDs next time. Something like this: (not tested)

```
$last_id = get_option('last_recipient_id');

$rcvr_id = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE ID > %d ORDER BY ID "), $last_id ) ; 
foreach($rcvr_id as $rv_id) { 
    $rcvr_id = $rv_id->ID; 

    // your actions
    //... 


} // end of foreach

// if some result was loaded, $rcvr_id holds the last ID value
if( $rcvr_id )
    update_option( 'last_recipient_id' , $rcvr_id );
```